# Using printf in the parameter of a method in Java

Tags: java, printf

I have a main class called CustomerTypeApp. It has a class variable `private static float itemPrice = 0.0f`. Within the main method is the following code:

```
String promptType = ("  To determine a discount for " + nf.format((float) itemPrice) + ", type in the... ...Select =>  ");
char customer = Validation.getChar(promptType);
```

I also have a class called Validation with a method getChar. The code is as follows:

```
public static char getChar(String prompt){
    String input;
    char choice;
    System.out.printf("  " + prompt);
    input = sc.nextLine();
    choice = input.charAt(0);
    return choice;
}
```

In the CustomerTypeApp class, the nf.format is obviously referring to NumberFormat. However, the professor has said we cannot use NumberFormat and instead have to use printf. The getChar method does use a printf statement. However, I am having trouble passing the value for the printf (variable?). Here's what I mean:
I edited my code for CustomerTypeApp as follows:

```
String promptType = ("  To determine a discount for $%.2s, type in the... ...Select => ");
```

The problem is I have to pass in itemPrice where the $%.2s is. I tried tacking it onto the end of promptType as follows:

```
("  To determine...$%.2s...Select => ", itemPrice);
```

However, I get an error stating ")" expected and ";" expected. I also tried adding it in the getChar method as follows:

```
System.out.printf("  " + prompt, itemPrice);
```

However, for that I get an error stating Cannot find symbol.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `String promptType = (" ` <- whats the point of the parenthesis? Is it supposed to be part of the String?

Comment: The professor included the parenthesis in the original code. I assume he was just keeping the string value together. It may not be necessary, but I left it on since he had put it on. In any event, if I'm trying to pass a value for the $%.2s, I would think I would need parens around the whole thing.

Comment: Cannot find symbol == where is the variable `prompt` declared (is it a variable?)

Answer (score 5):

Use 
`String.format("To determine...%f.2s...Select => ", itemPrice)`

Comment: That gives `"To determine...0.000000.2s...Select => "`. Did you mean `To determine...%.2f...Select =>`?

Comment: I caught that when I tested the code and fixed it. Thanks for mentioning it.